# how to get list of Lotus notes mail file's owners name

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

I wonder if it is possible to generate a list of email users and their owners to a text file? I'm a beginner in Lotus script ... can there be any database in domino administrator where can i find such data? [Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqOYB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code example:

```
Dim sess as new Notessession
Dim dbdir as NotesDBDirectory
Dim db as NotesDatabase
Dim Profile As NotesDocument

Set dbdir = New NotesDBDirectory("Servername")
Set db = dbdir.GetFirstDatabase(1247)
Do until db is nothing
    'expecting the mail files are located in subfolder mail, check the path
    If Ucase(Left(db.FilePath , 5)) = "MAIL\" Then
         If not db.IsOpen Then
             Call db.Open("","")
         End If
         Set Profile = db.GetProfileDocument("CalendarProfile")
         Print Profile.Owner(0) ' prints out the owner name to Client Status bar or Server console
    End If
    Set db = dbdir.GetNextDatabase
Loop
```

The line

```
Print Profile.Owner(0) ' prints out the owner name to Client
```

must be modified to match your needs. You can use the Lotus script write Statement.

Take a look at IBM help Center:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_NOTESDBDIRECTORY_CLASS.html
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_NOTESDATABASE_CLASS.html
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/de/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/LSAZ_WRITE_LB_STATEMENT.html

HTH, Markus

Answer (score 1):

you can use the NotesDBDirectory class to loop through all dbs on server. If the database resides in subfolder mail, you can get the database using the notes database class. Normally the title of the database is the owners Name. But you can also get the calendar Profile document and read the field owner.

Another approach: take a look in names.nsf. you can Export data as CSV-file ...

Greetz, Markus

Comment: Your code- description is ok, the other approach does not help here... But still +1

Comment: Exporting from names.nsf won't get you the owner that's entered into the profile doc for each mail file, but it will get you the FullName of the directory entry that is pointing to that file. And writing code to loop through names.nsf, get the server and path for each Person and/or mailin-db, and then open the mail file and get the calendar profile doc and read the owner item is the way I'd go about doing this because not all mail files are necessarily in the mail subfolder, and there could easily bemultiple servers,

Comment: You are right ... we just have only one Server, and all mail-files are located in subfolder mail. That's why i mentioned that ...

Comment: Do I understand that this is not possible?http://thepiyush.blogspot.com/2008/04/using-lotusscript-how-to-get-mail-files.html

Comment: Of course it is possible. The example in your posted link shows code for just the current database ... you Need to Access the databases inside the notesdbdirectory Loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'd iterate through the user documents in the server's names.nsf. Look at each user to see if they have an email database listed and, if so, output them to a text file.